# .equals() not evaluating to proper boolean

Tags: java

```
public class SparseMatrix {
    private final TreeMap<Integer,TreeMap<Integer,Double>> matrix;
    private final int rows;
    private final int cols;

    public SparseMatrix(int r, int c) {
        // Creates instances for matrix objects
        this.matrix = new TreeMap<>();

        // Assigns the matrix a number of rows and a number of columns
        this.rows = r;
        this.cols =  c;
    }

    public TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, Double>> getMatrix() {
        return matrix;
    }

    public static boolean equals(SparseMatrix a, SparseMatrix b) {
        if (a.getMatrix().equals(b.getMatrix()) == true) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Keys and values are inputted by the user then there's a test driver to make sure it works right, but it's not evaluating the matrices right. It tells me true every time. I'm assuming it's the == true and the equals comparator. It returns true if all the keys and values of both matrices are equal.

"new" command:

```
if (cmd.equals("new")) {
    String name = input.next();
    int rows = input.nextInt();
    int cols = input.nextInt();
    if (rows < 1 || cols < 1) {
        System.out.println("new: rows and/or cols less than 1: ");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    SparseMatrix m = new SparseMatrix(rows,cols);
    int i = input.nextInt();
    while (i >= 0) {
        int j = input.nextInt();
        double v = input.nextDouble();
        m.set(i,j,v);
        i = input.nextInt();
    }
    matrix.put(name,m);
    System.out.printf("new %s = %s\n", name, m);
}
```

The test driver part is:

```
String a = input.next();
if (!matrix.containsKey(a)) {
    System.out.println("equals: no such matrix: " + a);
    System.exit(1);
}
String b = input.next();

if (!matrix.containsKey(b)) {
    System.out.println("equals: no such matrix: " + b);
    System.exit(1);
}

System.out.printf("%s.equals(%s) = %b\n", a, b,
              SparseMatrix.equals(matrix.get(a),matrix.get(b)));
```

And the input looks like:

```
new name1 10 10 // new matrix with 10 rows and 10 columns
10 10 10.0 // int int double treemap
-1 // stops the input
```

Comment: Can we also see your test cases that are always returning true?

Comment: Is that all of the code? If so, then it would always return true because matrix is always just an empty tree map. Presumably there's more code involved (you mention user input); you need to provide more of the code to enable insight into a solution,

Comment: Code added for this! ^

Comment: Is matrix in your code for the new command the matrix field in SparseMatrix?

Comment: I'm assuming so, I honestly don't remember what I was thinking when making the driver (which works fine and shouldn't be touched)...Particularly unsure...I just added the getMatrix method. Not sure I need it for this.

Comment: In your "new" command, where/how is the variable "matrix" defined? It seems like what you must be doing is over-writing one instance of a variable somewhere, so you're comparing something to itself. But still not enough code to be clear.

Comment: Why did you remove all your code? Other people might learn something from it.

Comment: For whatever reason you are basically comparing one SparseMatrix to itself or the matrices are identical because of some error. The reason isn't apparent from the code you've posted. My best guess is it is the `set` method which you didn't include. Also not to nitpick but your equals method body can be replaced with one line: `return a.getMatrix().equals(b.getMatrix());` or `return a.matrix.equals(b.matrix);`.

Comment: I guess you can use return a.getMatrix().equals(b.getMatrix()); instead of whole if-then-else implementation.

Comment: And what is the implementation of equals() for the type returned by getMatrix()?

Comment: I wonder if a `Tree` requires a deep-search for the `equals()` ? Is this implemented?

Comment: Can you post the code for the `get`method you use in `SparseMatrix.equals(matrix.get(a),matrix.get(b)))` ?

Comment: @DWilches. Seems like a simple call to the standard api [TreeMap.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#get(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `matrix.get(a)` and `matrix.get(b)` returns the same `TreeMap`. Try to print the results to be sure.

As for comparisons, as long as the objects that you are trying to compare correctly overrides `equals` you can do this with the standard API:

```
public static boolean equals(SparseMatrix a, SparseMatrix b) {
    return matrix.get(a).equals(matrix.get(b));
}
```

I'm also a huge fan of libraries such as [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) and [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Utility methods such as Commons [Collections.isEqualCollection](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#isEqualCollection%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) and Guava [Maps.difference](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference%28java.util.Map,%20java.util.Map%29) may come in handy.